# Unknown type name 'TransportViewController'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.3

This maybe a simple mistake but i just can't seem to find out what is wrong with the error `Unknown type name 'TransportViewController'`. I am trying to pass xCoor and yCoor which is 2 `double` value to my 2nd view which is the TransportViewController. Here is my codes:

```
TransportViewController *xCoor;
TransportViewController *yCoor;
@property (retain, nonatomic) TransportViewController *xCoor;
@property (retain, nonatomic) TransportViewController *yCoor;
```

This 4 line is giving me the error

**MapViewController.h file**

```
#import "TransportViewController.h"
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController{
    TransportViewController *xCoor;
    TransportViewController *yCoor;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) TransportViewController *xCoor;
@property (retain, nonatomic) TransportViewController *yCoor;
```

**MapViewController.m file**

```
#import "TransportViewController.h"
@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize xCoor;
@synthesize yCoor;
.
.
.
- (IBAction) publicTransportAction:(id)sender{
    TransportViewController *view = [[TransportViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.xCoor = view;
    self.yCoor = view;
    xCoor.xGPSCoordinate = self.mapView.gps.currentPoint.x;
    yCoor.xGPSCoordinate = self.mapView.gps.currentPoint.y;
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:NO];
}
```

**TransportViewController.h file**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
@interface TransportViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    double xGPSCoordinate;
    double yGPSCoordinate;
}
@property(nonatomic)double xGPSCoordinate;
@property(nonatomic)double yGPSCoordinate;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. In short, you have directed the compiler:

- `MapViewController.h` needs `TransportViewController.h`
- and `TransportViewController.h` needs `MapViewController.h`

In actuality - *neither* are necessary in the headers. You can use **Forward Declarations** in both cases.

**MapViewController.h**

```
@class TransportViewController; // << forward declaration instead of inclusion

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController {
    TransportViewController *xCoor;
    TransportViewController *yCoor;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) TransportViewController *xCoor;
@property (retain, nonatomic) TransportViewController *yCoor;
@end
```

**TransportViewController.h**

```
@class MapViewController; // << not even needed, as MapViewController
                          //    does not exist in this header

@interface TransportViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    double xGPSCoordinate;
    double yGPSCoordinate;
}
@property(nonatomic)double xGPSCoordinate;
@property(nonatomic)double yGPSCoordinate;
@end
```

then your `#import`s can go in the `*.m` file where needed.

you should read up on forward declarations. you can't use them everywhere, but you can use them very often in headers instead of `#import`, and the can really reduce your build times.

Comment: Thanks for ur help and advice :) but for TransportViewController.h `@class MapViewController;` is needed as I only pasted a part of my code here.